# Django allauth telegram provider not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

Has anyone successfully implemented using allauth's telegram provider? I've followed the documentation and everything but it still does nothing.

Comment: Take a look at  [this one](https://dmytrostriletskyi.medium.com/the-telegram-login-for-your-website-on-django-3661f8ac7a2e)